# Java and MySQL Console REPL

Tags: java, mysql, read-eval-print-loop

I need to write a Java code that create a shell running `MySQL` console command  and can retain the interactive sesion until it is purposely destroyed.

To simulate it, this is my code.

```
    ProcessBuilder pb;
    pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "cmd.exe","/c","c://xampp//mysql//bin//mysql","-uroot");

    Process p = pb.start();

    OutputStream stdout = p.getOutputStream();
    InputStream stdin = p.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdin));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdout));

    boolean written = false;
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("loop... ");

        writer.write("show databases;\r\n\r\n");
        writer.flush();
        writer.newLine();
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
        writer.close(); //If not close, it cannot produce result

        String line;
        line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
```

Problem is, the code is only run once because `writer.close()` has been called in the loop. But if I don't call the `writer.close()`, it never response.

How can I achieve my objective?

Comment: First, please explain the purpose of launching `mysql` from Java.  And, is the question directed at MySQL, or at Java's ProcessBuilder?  What happens if you launch `cat` instead of `mysql`?

Comment: The purpose of launching MySQL from Java is to interactively send command and receive result from MySQL console. Not to interact through JDBC.

The final goal is actually developing a web based with REPL features to MySQL prompt.

Hopefully I make it clear.

Comment: Will the Java prevent the naughty hacker from saying `DROP DATABASE mysql`?

Comment: Keep in mind the performance overhead of going through cmd and mysql is significant compared to JDBC.

Comment: Hi Rick, it's ok... will run it on container for malicious code, or we will sanitize it.

The REPL is targeted MySQL for now, but later will make it into other alike interaction, eg: Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from `line = reader.readLine()`.  It doesn't return until a complete line has been found, which is indicated by the newline character in the output stream.  But when you are processing the output from `mysql`, you will not get a complete line, but a "prompt", such as

```
mysql> _
```

Additionally, it will ***never*** return `null` until the process it is reading from has *terminated* or otherwise closed its output stream.  So you can't use that as a loop-termination condition.  Instead, you should read the stream character-by-character, looking for an indication that the command you have submitted has completed.

I don't have mysql installed, by I do have sqlite3 installed, so I created a script which launches it with a test database "sql", queries table `t1` (single text column, two rows), and prints the output.  This is repeated 3 times.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/sqlite3", "sql");
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

// Don't use a BufferedReader; it waits for '\n' characters.
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());

// Our own "Buffered Reader" workspace 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Execute 3 times only ...
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {

   System.out.println("Command: select * from t1;");
   bw.write("select * from t1;\n");
   bw.write(".print !-DONE-!\n");
   bw.flush();

   System.out.println("Result:");
   // Repeat until magic phrase in read buffer
   while (true) {

      // Read characters one at a time...
      char ch = (char) isr.read();

      // Do our own newline processing.
      if (ch == '\n') {
         String line = sb.toString();   // Buffer to string
         sb.setLength(0);               // ... and clear buffer

         if (line.equals("!-DONE-!"))
            break;

         System.out.println(line);
      } else {
         sb.append(ch);
      }
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Output from `jshell pb.java`:

```
Command: select * from t1;
Result:
Hello world
Goodbye world!

Command: select * from t1;
Result:
Hello world
Goodbye world!

Command: select * from t1;
Result:
Hello world
Goodbye world!

|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> _
```

It seems that with `stdin` coming from, and `stdout` going to, another process, my `sqlite3` is refusing to emit the `sqlite>` prompt on the `stdout`.  This caused me much grief, and after an hour of fighting with various settings and command line options, I've given up, and just added a print command which prints the magic word `!-DONE-!`.  The output processing looks for this magic word, and breaks out of the result read-loop.

If you can figure out the magic incantation required to make `mysql` spit out the `mysql> _` prompt on `stdout`, then your break condition would be in the non-newline path, something like:

```
      } else {
         sb.append(ch);
         if (sb.length() == 7 && sb.toString().equals("mysql> ")) {
            sb.setLength(0);
            break;
         }
      }
```

Comment: Hi AJNeufield, I try to apply it to MySQL console but to no avail. I still need to call close method.

Comment: When I was struggling with the break condition for my result read loop, I had `System.out.println("[" + sb + "] ch="+((int)ch));` in the loop.  It helped me figure out what was coming back.  Edit your question and add your updated code (don’t remove the original) along with the output the debug statement produces (you can trim some of the lines from the output, but I definitely want to see what it outputs before & after it encounters the newlines.

Comment: Hi AJNeufield, will try out the solution. But will give you bounty for detail explanation on the behavior, it give me more understanding of the processbuilder and a way to troubleshoot them.

Comment: Thank-you for the bounty.  But please do post the debug output, if you can’t get it working.  We’re not done yet.  This problem isn’t answered until we have a green checkmark beside a working answer that has solved your problem and can help other people as well.